# how create triangle using css

Tags: css

Please any one help me how create below diagram using css.

```
    ________/\_______
   |                |
   |                |
   |                |
   |________________|
```

Please help me how to it will done using css.and only **div** should be use.

Comment: Have you searched existing questions mate?

Comment: hint : `border-style: solid dahsed`

Comment: I am asking above triangle @diEcho

Comment: After making some [minor changes](http://jsfiddle.net/4ZeCz/2820/). Now, all you need to do is figure out how to align it on the top.

Comment: Another one here: http://jsfiddle.net/pnmzsoLj/1/

Comment: Reference: [CSS Shapes](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/)

Comment: here's one: http://jsfiddle.net/alexwcoleman/6ue8vvba/2/

Comment: Hi @leftside, How decrease border width for above triangle, i need one pixel, can please help me ho to do it

Comment: i put an answer below.

Comment: Here is another one without any CSS ----> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ZeCz/2828/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/alexwcoleman/6ue8vvba/

```
.box {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    height:100px;
    width:300px;
    margin-top:100px;
    background:#fff;
}
.box:after, .box:before {
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.box:after {
    border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #fff;
    border-width: 30px;
    margin-left: -30px;
}
.box:before {
    border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #000;
    border-width: 31px;
    margin-left: -31px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code use for create triangle:

```
HTML:
<div id="talkbubble"></div>

CSS:
#talkbubble {
   width: 120px;
   height: 80px;
   background: red;
   position: relative;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
#talkbubble:before {
   content: "";
position: absolute;
right: 43%;
bottom: 100%;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-left: 13px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 25px solid red;
border-right: 11px solid transparent;
}
```

SEE DEMO HERE:[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JentiDabhi/53vL1jhb/)